# Increase excerpts length on Schema Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, schema

I am trying hard to get the excerpts length atleast 250 words, but it is stuck on 50 words. I tried changing in Reading Setting, Even in custom php editing.
I added following code too in functions.php

```
function excerpt($limit) {
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
       array_pop($excerpt);
       $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
    } else {
       $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    }   
    $excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
    return $excerpt;
}

function content($limit) {
  $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
  if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
  } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
  } 
  $content = preg_replace('/[.+]/','', $content);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
  return $content;
}`
```

Here's the [homepage](http://franksms.com) if you want to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
echo string_limit_words($excerpt,250);
```

where 250 is the number of words

Comment: But before it showed 50 words right? Do you have html in you words? I have no other idea sorry.

Comment: Yeah. i am still thinking that its may be defined somewhere else or with some other name. anyways thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have html in you words? maybe it count <p> tags for example